# Making one script talk to another and back

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

```
    public void Start()
    {
       GiveAmmo(2, 100);  // pick up ammo test
    }

    public void GiveAmmo(int code, int amount)
    {
        Ammo[code] += amount;
    }
```

I've been trying for several weeks to get a script(gun) to talk to another(inventory) and have it talk back (inventory to gun).

```
// Gun to inventory
PlayerInventory inventory = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerInventory>();
inventory.UseAmmo(code, ammoInClip, clipSize);
```

```
// Inventory to Gun
   public void UseAmmo(int code, int inClip, int clipSize)
   {  
        while (Ammo[code] > 0 && inClip < clipSize) 
        {   
            {
                Ammo[code] --;
                inClip ++;
            }
        }
// send back ammoInClip
   }
```

I've been trying Singletons and static combinations, but nothing works.  What are the magic words?
I don't want to mention the error messages because the last time, it closed my question and told me to RTFM.
(Unless there's an easy way load a gun that I don't know about???)

Comment: you dont show how your code snippets fit together but if they are in different classes, then just like using the unity components, you need to get your components and use them

Answer (score 0):

If you'll have only one inventory in the game, the singleton pattern should really resolve your problems :

```
public class PlayerInventory: MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerInventory Instance;
    
    //Singleton initialization
    private void Awake(){
        if(Instance) Destroy(this);
        else Instance = this;
    }

//Rest of your playerInventory class}
```

Then in your gun code use :

```
    PlayerInventory.Instance.UseAmmo(code, ammoInClip, clipSize);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use static floats, or you can make it so it is a direct reference (public GameObject player).